# Caption shows but the image is not in pdf

Tags: graphics, floats

When I put the following code in latex

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=8cm]{nnn}
\caption{Different iterative schemes graphical behaviors.}
\end{figure}
```

Then I get only caption in the generated pdf as shown  [image]. I need the figure too. This code works in my general files. But I'm trying this in a specific journal format and I faced the problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant rest of your code, \document...\end{}, dropping what's not needed to show your problem. Then it's also clear, whether or not you are missing a relevant package.

Comment: Please provide a complete small document, from `documentclass` to the `\end{document}`. It may be, that you have option  `draft`  at document class. In normal circumstances image should appear.

Comment: do you get an error in the log?, why have  you tagged this for bibtex??

Comment: Note you should almost never have `\includegraphics[height=5cm, width=8cm]` as that scales by different amounts in each direction, distorting the image